# How do I stop having a black screen in manual mode

Tags: canon, manual-mode, color-black

I have a Canon t6i and recently the pictures I have taken in manual mode are coming out black. When I use live shooting the screen is black. However there is a brief moment when the camera 'focuses' that I can see what Im taking a picture of, but the pictures still come out black. I have tried changing the aperture and shutter speed but it didn't help. Ive also checked if the shutter was stuck. All other modes seem to be working fine.

Comment: What are the lighting conditions when you take these black pictures? What ISO, shutter speed, and aperture are you selecting?

Comment: Why are you using Manual mode? "I have tried changing the aperture and shutter speed but it didn't help." What did you change them to? Random settings? Do you understand the exposure triangle?

Comment: Can you add the aperture, shutter speed, and ISO of an underexposed photo from manual mode and a correctly exposed photo from another mode? As others have answered, it's probably that your exposure settings in manual mode are to dark, but that would allow someone to confirm or disprove.

Comment: I see a lot of condescending answers here. Why must you assume he or she did something wrong. It's pretty difficult to get a totally black picture unless you are shooting at a scene in your backyard at midnight. Usually, you will get something on the screen or in your photos, even if they are dim.

Comment: These comments are not accurate or helpful.
If you are shooting in a studio with studio flash, and manual mode for aperture and shutter speed (I know what I am doing), the screen will go very dim because it is measuring the ambient light in the studio. This makes composing and focusing impossible with the M3. Absolutely no problem with an EOS 1Ds or a 5D, or anything with an optical viewfinder. If there is a menu command on the M3 then I cannot find it. And, before anyone dodges the questions and asks why I am using an M3 in studio, why not? I prefer full frame, but the camera should be up to

Comment: @6581william To the contrary — when using manual mode in a dim situation, it's _really_ easy to get an apparently-all-dark image.

Comment: @RobertBell I'm not sure which comments you are referring to, but it really sounds like you have different problem, because the question says "the pictures I have taken in manual mode are coming out black", not that the screen is dim while composing.

Answer (score 6):

> I have tried changing the aperture and shutter speed but it didn't help.

Not to state the obvious, but what you change the aperture and shutter speeds *to* matters a lot. What were the settings you used? Also, check the ISO and exposure compensation settings.

A good way start is to take a photo in Program mode. If the exposure looks good, check the values that the camera chooses for aperture, shutter speed, and ISO. Switch to manual and use the same settings that the camera did, and you should get a similar exposure (assuming the lighting hasn't changed).

Also, learn to use the light meter. In manual mode, the meter will show you how much light the sensor will see given the current exposure settings.

Answer (score 5):

When you're in manual mode, you can shoot yourself in the foot all you want. This includes underexposing to the point of having a black frame.  **Check your meter.**  Unlike all the other automated modes, in M mode, the camera doesn't automatically adjust your settings to shove your meter's "needle" to 0.  This is actually a feature, not a bug.  But if you *haven't* shot in M mode before, you may be so used to the camera always putting the needle on 0 for you that you no longer look at it, or think you need to do anything like that.

"0", btw, isn't always exactly correct, it's just what your camera's autoexposure system *thinks* is correct.  Which is why we like having M mode: for those times the AE system is wrong and the meter is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Do not take this wrong, but all the other modes are automatic. This one depends on you, so... learn how to control the camera.

The situation you describe sounds to me that it is very dark, because you say that the camera focus for a moment and that is the only moment you see what are you photographing. That can be the focus asistant light. The rest of the time the scene is black.

Try to learn photography in daylight not in the dark.

Find this indicator on your camera:

https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=exposure+indicator

It tells you the light is ok when it is on the middle. Read your camera manual.